# Expected end of line etc. but found unknown token

Tags: applescript

set passCode to "I'mTheBitCoinMinerr"
display dialog "To access the following page, you need to enter your password" default answer "Enter password here" buttons {"Submit"} default button 1
set passInput to text returned of result
if passInput is passCode then
    display dialog "Access granted" buttons {"Continue"} default button 1
    repeat
    display dialog "Do you wish to cancel or not?" buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"}
            display dialog "This page is my page of linkz

```
Page navigation.
Where do you want to go?

Answers:
Canvasrider
Youtube
Instagram" default answer "Enter a valid answer here" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
    set pageNav to text returned of result
    if pageNav is "Canvasrider" then
        display dialog "Link to my Canvasrider profile: canvasrider.com/users/thestuntmaster125

Page navigation.
Where do you want to go?

Answers:
MinecraftForum
Planetminecraft
Back" default answer "Enter a valid answer here" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
    else if pageNav is "Youtube" then
        display dialog "Link to my YouTube profile: http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUPOC8-sCiqIMtrA5Yw4fMA

Page navigation.
Where do you want to go?

Answers:
MinecraftForum
Planetminecraft
Back" default answer "Enter a valid answer here" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
    else
        display dialog "Link to my Instagram profile: Instagram.com/mcaddict125

    Page navigation.
    Where do you want to go?

    Answer:
    MinecraftForum
    Planetminecraft
    Back Enter a valid answer here" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
    end if
```

end repeat

else
display dialog "Access denied" buttons {"OK"}

end if

^^^From the top to the bottom "end if" is my unfinished code for a password locked link page with links to my profiles on other sites. But whenever I try to compile/run it, it says "Expected end of line etc. but found unknown token" and my code appears valid! I am new at Applescript so if the answer is simple, I won't be surprised. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
set passCode to "I'mTheBitCoinMinerr"
display dialog "To access the following page, you need to enter your password" default answer "Enter password here" buttons {"Submit"} default button 1
set passInput to text returned of result

if passInput is passCode then
    display dialog "Access granted" buttons {"Continue"} default button 1

    repeat
        display dialog "Do you wish to cancel or not?" buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"}
        pageNav to text returned of (display dialog "This page is my page of linkz

            Page navigation.
            Where do you want to go?

            Answers:
            Canvasrider
            Youtube
            Instagram" default answer "Enter a valid answer here" buttons {"OK"} default button 1)

        if pageNav is "Canvasrider" then
            display dialog "Link to my Canvasrider profile: canvasrider.com/users/thestuntmaster125

                Page navigation.
                Where do you want to go?

                Answers:
                MinecraftForum
                Planetminecraft
                Back" default answer "Enter a valid answer here" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
        else if pageNav is "Youtube" then
            display dialog "Link to my YouTube profile: http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUPOC8-sCiqIMtrA5Yw4fMA

                    Page navigation.
                    Where do you want to go?

                    Answers:
                    MinecraftForum
                    Planetminecraft
                    Back" default answer "Enter a valid answer here" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
        else
            display dialog "Link to my Instagram profile: Instagram.com/mcaddict125

                            Page navigation.
                            Where do you want to go?

                            Answer:
                            MinecraftForum
                            Planetminecraft
                            Back Enter a valid answer here" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
        end if
    end repeat
else
    display dialog "Access denied" buttons {"OK"}
end if
```